# MediaController Visibility

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have an Android application that uses a VideoView to play videos and I am also using a media controller.

My problem is I am unable to prevent the media controller from disappearing while the video is playing and i would also like to make the media controller visible before the video starts so that the user can use the media controller to initially start the video. I have tried using using MediaController.show(0), but that didn't solve my problem. Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

    mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);

    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            playVideo();
        }
    });

    mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.pause();
            }
        }
    });

    mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });

    mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                current = null;
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void playVideo() {
    try {
        final String path = "http://toop.voxelperfect.net/video6.mp4";

        System.out.println("path "+path);
        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, "File URL/path is empty",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("else ");
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                System.out.println("mVideoView.start() ");

                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            current = path;
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path)); 
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mc.show(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I too have had problems with Android's built in `MediaController` widget. You may want to consider making your own set of controls within the layout itself and just call methods on the `VideoView` when one of your controls is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a nested class that implements the MediaController and overrided the hide method.